# How is BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION supposed to work?

Tags: c++, boost, macros

I'm reading [boost's config/suffix.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/config/suffix.hpp), and I'm surprised with the following code:

```
//  Workaround for the unfortunate min/max macros defined by some platform headers

#define BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION

// <skipped unimportant lines>

namespace std {
  template <class _Tp>
  inline const _Tp& min BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION (const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b) {
    return __b < __a ? __b : __a;
  }
  template <class _Tp>
  inline const _Tp& max BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION (const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b) {
    return  __a < __b ? __b : __a;
  }
}
```

This actually seems to be a valid thing to make the definitions of `min` and `max` functions compile when the same-named macros are defined. But why would this be useful at the actual call site? Wouldn't the macro actually substitute when the functions are called? I've tried to make a simple test, "emulating" this setup:

```
#include <iostream>

#define PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION
#define max(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(y):(x))

namespace test
{
int max PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION (int a, int b)
{
    std::cerr << "Function max\n";
    return a<b?b:a;
}
}

int main()
{
    int x=test::max(5,6);
    std::cout << "x="<<x<<"\n";
}
```

And, as expected, I get a compilation error due to expansion of `max` macro. So, how is boost's macro substitution prevention supposed to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not supposed to do what you think it's supposed to do.

If a `min` or `max` macro is defined, and the user wishes to call those `std::min` or `std::max` functions, it's the user's responsibility to make sure the macro is suppressed. Possibly again using `BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION`, possibly using parentheses (`(std::min) (...)`).

All the use of `BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION` is doing here is preventing a syntax error from being raised for the *definition* of `std::min` and `std::max`, like you figured out already. It would happily expand `min` as a macro if the header had used `inline const _Tp& min (const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)`, resulting in something like `inline const _Tp& ((const _Tp& __a) < (const _Tp& __b) ? (const _Tp& __a) : (const _Tp& __b))`. But if code doesn't actually use `min` or `max`, then including that header file should be harmless.

Answer (score 0):

For this line of code to compile correctly and suppress the Marco expansion, add `PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION`:

```
int x = test::max(5, 6); // will generate compilation error
int x = test::max PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION(5, 6); // compiles okay
```

So it is actually more convenient just to write:

```
int x = (test::max)(5, 6);
```